# MSER to binary image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, mser

How to store the mser regions find out from an image as a binary image variable? 
I tried to get MSER regions by detectMSERFeatures function and it returns corresponding object. I could plot it, but don't know how to convert it as a binary image. I need all the regions in same binary image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MSERRegions` objects that you get back from `detectMSERFeatures`, includes the `PixelList` property. It contains the coordinates of pixels that belong to the regions, and you can use them to set pixels in the binary image.